# NGINX error during compilation sources

Tags: nginx, compilation

I need help cause i get error when compiling nginx v1.9.12

**Compilation code**

```
 ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --without-http_rewrite_module
```

**Error return**

```
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_zone_module.o \
    objs/ngx_modules.o \
    -ldl -lpthread -lcrypt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz \
    -Wl,-E
sed -e "s|%%PREFIX%%|/etc/nginx|" \
        -e "s|%%PID_PATH%%|/var/run/nginx.pid|" \
        -e "s|%%CONF_PATH%%|/etc/nginx/nginx.conf|" \
        -e "s|%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%|/var/log/nginx/error.log|" \
        < man/nginx.8 > objs/nginx.8
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /opt/nginx-1.9.12 »
```

Someone can help ?

Comment: First of all you should add configure line (with all options you have specified) to the question. The second - it really hard to understand the error message because it's not in English.

Comment: @ALex_hha The only localized, non-English part is "quittant le répertoire", which google translate tells me means "Leaving directory". The double arrow thing is [how French does quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about this message

```
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_zone_module.o \
        objs/ngx_modules.o \
        -ldl -lpthread -lcrypt -lpcre -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz \
        -Wl,-E
sed -e "s|%%PREFIX%%|/opt/nginx-1.9.12|" \
                -e "s|%%PID_PATH%%|/opt/nginx-1.9.12/logs/nginx.pid|" \
                -e "s|%%CONF_PATH%%|/opt/nginx-1.9.12/conf/nginx.conf|" \
                -e "s|%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%|/opt/nginx-1.9.12/logs/error.log|" \
                < man/nginx.8 > objs/nginx.8
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/nginx-1.9.12'
```

it's not an error at all. The nginx has been compiled successfully. All you need is to install it

```
# make install
```

Comment: yes it's about this message